# Centreon (nagios) to Prometheus : bash custom check

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

We have a Centreon server (based on nagios) with different custom check in bash.

For example, a script that check every 2 minutes if there is an error in a CSV file :

- If there is more than 0 error the check comes out as WARNING
- Otherwise, OK

Something like :

```sh
count_files=$(find $1 -name "*.csv" | wc -l)

if [[ $count_files -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo "WARNING - Error files found"
    exit 1
else
    echo "OK - No error file found"
    exit 0
fi
```

We are planning to change Centreon to Prometheus/Grafana but I was wondering how I can have custom bash check in Prometheus.

Should I put my script on these VMs and expose the result in Prometheus format ? Like this :

```
# HELP csv_checker Check error in csv files
# TYPE csv_checker gauge
csv_checker 20
```

If yes, how can I do that ?

Prometheus will check periodically on this endpoint ? How can I manage that with ~300 VMs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use NodeExporter's feature called [Textfile Collector](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#textfile-collector)

1. Setup Node exporter on each VM and add a cronjob calling your bash script to collect the data every 2min (`*/2 * * * *`):

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   set -euo pipefail

   csv_files=$(find /mnt -name "*.csv" | wc -l)
   echo "# HELP csv_files Amount of .csv files
   # TYPE csv_files gauge
   csv_files{} $csv_files" > /opt/node_exporter/textfile_collector/csv_files.prom.$$
   mv /opt/node_exporter/textfile_collector/csv_files.prom.$$ /opt/node_exporter/textfile_collector/csv_files.prom
   ```
2. Setup Prometheus to collect metrics from your VMs
3. Setup Alertmnager
4. Add alert rule like:

   ```
     - alert: Errors in CSV files
       expr: csv_files != 0
       for: 1m
       labels:
         severity: warning
       annotations:
         summary: Errors in CSV files on the instance {{ $labels.instance }}
         description: "VALUE = {{ $value }}\n  LABELS = {{ $labels }}"
   ```

Prometheus will check all your hosts with given interval and notify about every instance with .csv files in the `/target_folder`

Comment: This confirms what I had seen, thank you